# Convert C bitwise statement to vb.net

Tags: c++, vb.net, bit-manipulation

I have a open source project I downloaded to help me through a byte array. I need to convert

```
int x = fgetc(inpFile);
x |= fgetc(inputfile) <<8;
x |= fgetc(inputfile) <<16;
x |= fgetc(inputfile) <<24;
```

to vb.net.  The fgetc and inpFile I understand.  Unfortunately I don't know C++ and I am thin on bitwise operations.

The file format I am trying to interpret (I'm working on an embroidery format reader) is poorly documented, and instructs me that 
"Address HEX 0008 to 0010 = 3 Bytes pointing to beginning of .... next block of byte array ... "

I'm simply trying to calculate the same value from these three bytes that the example code above does.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: That reads a little endian 32 bit signed integer

Comment: For clarity, are you reading 3 bytes or 4? The code example is reading 4 bytes, but you cite that the documentation says 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i will go with this

```
 dim x as integer = fgetc(inpFile) or 
                    fgetc(inpFile) << 8 or 
                    fgetc(inpFile) << 16 or 
                    fgetc(inpFile) <<24
```

Comment: This works with some mod.  I actually already have the entire file read into a byte array, so instead of using the fgetc from the input file, I used cint and the byte array positions:

Comment: Dim pecstart As Integer = CInt(b(8)) Or (CInt(b(9)) << 8) Or (CInt(b(10)) << 16) Or (CInt(b(11)) << 24)

Answer (score 1):

You could go with `BinaryReader`, that automatically reads in [Little Endian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

```
Dim reader As BinaryReader
Dim x As Integer

reader = New BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
x = reader.ReadInt32()
```